# How to transform, with ClojureScript, a number into the same number of spaces such that it can be used by the println function?

Tags: clojurescript

Consider the following hypothetical function:

```
(map #(println (:level %) (:data %)) (category-visitor))
```

where

```
(category-visitor)
```

represents a vector of ( nested ) maps, and

```
(:level % )
```

represents an integer.

I want to indent the printed line with a number of spaces equal to

```
(:level %)
```

such that the hierarchical relations between the maps is visualized.

The question is how I can transform a number into the same number of spaces such that it can be used by the println function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `repeat` function to generate as many spaces as you need as a sequence and then convert them to string:

```
(defn indent-str [level]
  (apply str (repeat level " ")))

(println (indent-str 5) "x")
;;=>      x
```